# Biblatex: Combine verbose-trad2 with authoryear

Tags: biblatex

I am currently using verbose-trad2 for my bibliography but I need to tweak it a little bit.
I would like to achieve this result:

- Piva F. (2008). Storia di Leda. Da bracciante a dirigente di partito. Milano: Franco Angeli, pp.
  85-90.

(Lastname N.(year).Title.Address:publisher,pp)

So basically I want to have the year in parentheses after the author(s)

My setup is this at the moment:

```
% Bibliografia
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}     
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,            
            language=italian,
            backend=biber,  
            ibidpage=true,
            backref=true,
            backrefstyle=none,
            bibstyle=numeric,
        ]{biblatex} 
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\NewBibliographyString{ibidemloccit,ibidemnoloccit}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
  idem           = {\autocap{i}d},
  ibidemloccit   = {\mkbibemph{\autocap{i}bid\adddot}},
  ibidemnoloccit = {\mkbibemph{\autocap{i}vi}},
}

\xpatchbibmacro{author}
  {\printnames{author}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
       {\printnames{author}}}
     {\printnames{author}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:editor}
  {\printnames{editor}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
        {\printnames{editor}}}
     {\printnames{editor}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchbibmacro{bbx:translator}
  {\printnames{translator}}
  {\iffootnote
     {\ifthenelse{\ifciteidem\AND\NOT\boolean{cbx:noidem}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:idem}}
        {\printnames{translator}}}
     {\printnames{translator}}}
  {}{}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \printtext{%
    \bibhyperlink{cite\csuse{cbx@lastcite@\thefield{entrykey}}}{%
      \ifloccit
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemloccit}%
         \global\toggletrue{cbx:loccit}}
        {\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidemnoloccit}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simpler than I expected. I just needed to change `bibstyle=numeric` to `bibstyle=authoryear`.